# NodeJS - Generating invalid totp code

Tags: node.js

So I have to login on a site, which has TOTP code. I have made simple NodeJS script, which would get me the TOTP code, but it's invalid all the time.

```
var notp = require('notp');
var base32 = require('thirty-two');
var key = 'KEYHERE';
var token = notp.totp.gen(key, 30);
console.log(token);
var login = notp.totp.verify(token, key);
if (!login) {
    return console.log('Token invalid');
}
console.log('Token valid, sync value is %s', login.delta);
```

Also, I have synced my time (not sure if I did it right then). Could someone help me to fix this code or syncing time on the server. Server is from France

Answer (score 0):

you can use npm module timesync 
Example :

```
// create a timesync instance 
var ts = timesync({
  server: '...',  // either a single server, 
  peers: [...]    // or multiple peers 
});

// get notified on changes in the offset 
ts.on('change', function (offset) {
  console.log('offset from system time:', offset, 'ms');
}

// get the synchronized time 
console.log('now:', new Date(ts.now()));
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand?

Comment: Yes, I'm generating my token first using my secret key and then I'm trying to verify it. But it comes out wrong, but my server is synced, still wrong

Answer (score 0):

have you generate and verify the notp

```
 var notp = {};
    notp.gen = function(key, opt) {
        opt = opt || {};
        var time = opt.time || 30;
        var _t = Date.now();

        // Time has been overwritten.
        if(opt._t) {
            if(process.env.NODE_ENV != 'test') {
                throw new Error('cannot overwrite time in non-test environment!');
            }
            _t = opt._t;
        }

        // Determine the value of the counter, C
        // This is the number of time steps in seconds since T0
        opt.counter = Math.floor((_t / 1000) / time);

        return hotp.gen(key, opt);
    };
notp.verify = function(token, key, opt) {
    opt = opt || {};
    var time = opt.time || 30;
    var _t = Date.now();

    // Time has been overwritten.
    if(opt._t) {
        if(process.env.NODE_ENV != 'test') {
            throw new Error('cannot overwrite time in non-test environment!');
        }
        _t = opt._t;
    }

    // Determine the value of the counter, C
    // This is the number of time steps in seconds since T0
    opt.counter = Math.floor((_t / 1000) / time);

    return hotp.verify(token, key, opt);
};
module.exports.totp = totp;
```

Comment: Hello, I can't generate it. I already have my own key from that website where I'm trying to login.

Comment: not getting what is the error you are getting??you are getting  token valid or invalid???and where you have use notp.....